# Static charge, PVC pipe and water

Tags: electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, materials, hydraulics

I know it's possible for a PVC pipe to develop a staic charge due to fluids flowing through them. This is a twist on that idea.

Can a sealed length of pvc (say 3.5 feet in length) - tethered below the surface in a flow of water (river or stream), develop an ESD charge on the inside of the PVC pipe surface? Would the conductivity of the water disipate any potential charge? Can the inside surface develop a different potential than the outside surface?

Comment: would the water connect both surfaces?

Comment: No. The water is strictly flowing around the outside surface. There are electronics housed inside the PVC tube that take and record measurements.